# Ruby RestClient Openssl Error OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, openssl

I need help with resolving openssl problem.
OS X 10.11.1

```
which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016

rvm version
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

gem -v
2.5.2

bundle show | grep rest
  * rest-client (1.8.0)
```

So, as you can see, all is up to date.
But i still get error:

```
RestClient.get('https://www.googleapis.com')
RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

But https on github works pretty well:

```
RestClient.get('https://github.com').code
 => 200
```

I already read this 
http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Nothing helps. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Google does not support SSL v3.0 anymore.

Comment: Some strange thing, that on my other mac there is no such problem, and on FreeBSD server there is no problem too (openssl version 1.0.1p)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed Eric platon google doesn't support SSL v3.0 anymore, but for mac and ruby, rvm and openssl the problem is that even you link openssl and you are using the last openssl, the ruby is compiled against the system openssl,
so please try this:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-X.Y.Z --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

then it should work,

```
irb(main):001:0> RestClient.get('https://www.googleapis.com')
RestClient::NotFound: 404 Not Found
```

and please update openssl with brew to the last version, this worked for me with the version:

```
╭─ ~  2.4.0@learn  SBCL 1.3.16 
╰─ brew --prefix openssl                                                                                                255 ↵  06:57 Dur  3371  16:34:01
/usr/local/opt/openssl
╭─ ~  2.4.0@learn  SBCL 1.3.16 
╰─ /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl version                                                                                           ✓  3373  17:05:45
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```